# mousemove event is fired with IE and firefox but it is not fired with chrome

Tags: openlayers-2, events, chrome, firefox

I am using mousemove event to do some code when the mouse get over features, the code below is working well with IE and firefox but It is not working with chrome

```
$(this.map.getViewport()).on('mousemove', function(evt) {
    var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(map.getEventPixel(evt),
        function(feature, layer) {
            return feature;
        });
    if (feature) {
        //do my code
    } else {
        don't do anything
    }
});
```

any suggestion?

Comment: What isn't working exactly? And do you you have any errors in developer console in chrome?

Comment: No I don't have any errors. The event mousemove is not fired in chrome, but it is fired in firefox. it may be jquery issue

Comment: This problem is solved, I just restart my machine. I think I must to clean chrome cache